# How to determine the current week number?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to put the current week number in the subject of outgoing mail.

Below gives me this week + 1.

I used to have 2016, now have 365. Problem is still here.

I tried `Format(Now - 1, "ww")` but it doesn't give current week - 1 week, my logic behind this was Format(Now - 1, "YYYY-MM-DD") which outputs today - one day's date.

```vb
Sub SendMail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        
        '.HTMLBody = "<p style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Text here, but deleted in this moment..</p>" & .HTMLBody
        '.Attachments.Add "C:\temp\Bok1.xlsx"
        
        '.To = ""
        .Subject = "v" & Format(Now - 1, "ww") & " - PR11"
        
        '.Send
    End With

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) has some optional parameters you might consider, such as *FirstDayOfWeek* and *FirstWeekOfYear*.

Comment: Yeah I know, not cleaver enough to understand the fundament I guess, also this should work without any -1 etc but it doesn't cause of a know Excel bugg. Have read countless articles on this (some posts even on the forums) but cant get my head around the supposed workarounds I have found, well allegedly working solutions.

Comment: Sub formatDemo135()
    Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date, "WW)
End Sub - if yes, then this dosent work or I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: Yes I have tried 135 different ways so far, to find a solution for this problem

Comment: I have still getting wrong week, its atm week 17 and this gives me 18 still

Comment: Sub find_week_number()

Week_Num = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbMonday)

MsgBox "Today’s week number is " & Week_Num

End Sub

Comment: what are you getting if you type my code just above right here, latest comment

Comment: Sub find_week_number137()
Week_Num = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbSunday)
Debug.Print "Today’s week number is " & Week_Num
'still giving 18 which is wrong week number
End Sub

Comment: `Format(Date, "ww",,vbFirstFullWeek)`?

Comment: YES! It is outputing 17!!! Sub find_week_number140()
Debug.Print Format(Date, "ww", , vbFirstFullWeek)
End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) has optional parameters:

- `FirstDayOfWeek`
- `FirstWeekOfYear`

Based on the comments, it looks like you're looking for:

```
Format(Date, "ww",,vbFirstFullWeek)
```

where `vbFirstFullWeek` means:

> Start with the first full week of the year.